# How to switch between post's texts with a button

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first question here and I'm a beginner in the coding scene.

For now, my question is a simple one. I want to create a button that switches between texts. For example, a post on a blog that is written in Portuguese and which, with a simple click of a button, changes the text to English. Believe me that I've searched a lot but i haven't still figured out the right code. Because I want the reader to have the option to switch between both texts "endlessly". I've managed to create a switch button but it didn't return the original text when I clicked on the button for the second time. I don't want the button to disappear either. The second text (which activates with the first click on the button, should appear on the same spot as the original text.

Thank you in advance for your help and please let me know if I wasn't clear in something.

**EDIT**

So I managed to create this button (snippet) but i need two more things:

- for the button to change it's name as well, so that it reads "Read in English" when the text is in Portuguese and that it reads "Read in Portuguese" when the text is in English. Where should I make the change? In the button tag? And how?
- is it possible to remove the blue border that appears when i click on the button?

```js
function readEnglish() {
    var x = document.getElementById('en');
    var y = document.getElementById('pt');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
        y.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
     y.style.display = 'block';
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
.EnglishButton {
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 border: 2px solid #555555;
 padding: 5px 5px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: Candara;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin: 4px 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 10px;
 position:absolute;
}

.EnglishButton:hover {background-color: #F2F8F2}

.EnglishButton:active {
 background-color: #F2F8F2;
 box-shadow: 0 1px #F2F8F2;
 transform: translateY(1px)
```

```html
<p id="pt">Português</p>
<p id="en" style ="display: none;">Inglês</p>

<button class="EnglishButton" onclick="readEnglish()">Read in English</button>
```

Comment: your question is too broad, please add `code` of what you are doing so we might actually help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

> Button's value now change on click accordingly as text

---

This might be is what you are looking for:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('pt');
    var y = document.getElementById('en');
    var z = document.getElementById('bt');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
        y.style.display = 'none';
        z.innerHTML = "Change to English";
    } else {
     y.style.display = 'block';
        x.style.display = 'none';
        z.innerHTML = "Change to Português";
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="bt" onclick="myFunction()">Change to Português</button>


<p id="pt" style ="display:none;">This is meant to be text in portegues language</p>

<p id="en">This is text in English language</p>
```

Comment: Yes it is! I saw online an example just like yours but missing the 'y' variable, which is exactly what I was missing. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Already did! Yet if you could help me with just two more things, I would be very grateful. Please check the edit i made in the original post please.

Answer (score 0):

To simply answer your question I have added a snippet that does this. Though if you are planning to have lots of articles or dynamic content you would need to abstract it a bit more.

If you are using a framework like rails, there are better options for multi language support and I would advise looking into them.

`Hope this helps:`

https://jsfiddle.net/j2Lqq4tv/

Comment: Yes it helps! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Just edited the post because I have two more questions with which I could use some help. Please check it if you can.

Comment: Youll need to ask the guy that you marked the accepted answer, i didnt write that code you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Google Translate Plugin](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/) for your website. Here is a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJmcqK-ZGvg) to YouTube video explaining the process

However, if you just want to apply a simple solution to translate a blogpost, here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1w591p8/1/) solution that you can apply to a simple blogpost. But solutions like these are not much scalable, you have to manually write translations in every page.

```
var blog = document.getElementById('blog');
var translate = document.getElementById('translate');

dict = {
en: "Hello, my name is Gaurav Grover. How are you? Hello, my name is Gaurav Grover. How are you? Hello, my name is Gaurav Grover. How are you?",
pt: "Olá, meu nome é Gaurav Grover. Como você está? Olá, meu nome é Gaurav Grover. Como você está? Olá, meu nome é Gaurav Grover. Como você está?"
};
translate.onclick = abc;
function abc() {
  var lang = blog.dataset.language;
  if(lang == "en") {
    blog.textContent = dict.pt;
    blog.setAttribute('data-language', "pt");
  } else if(lang == "pt") {
    blog.textContent = dict.en;
    blog.setAttribute('data-language', "en"); 
    }
}
```

Considering the scalability problem, If you are planning to translate more than one text on a page manually, then you better use a dedicated plugin for it like [translate.js](http://www.openxrest.com/translatejs/index.html#)

Comment: I'm translating the posts myself because they're small articles and I don't trust very much in Google Translator. It does get the job done but not perfectly. So that's why I just needed that button. Thanks for your help though, I might actually consider using your solution in the future :)